# Add KeyEvent for calculator numpad in JavaFX using MVC

Tags: javafx

I created in Eclipse a simple calculator using JavaFx and MVC pattern. I would like to add keylisteners in order to press the buttons of my calculator by simply pressing the buttons in my keyboard. I tried to add #onKeyPress in SceneBuilder and then a method onKeypress (with some coding inside)  in my Controller class but nothing happens.Could you please give some general instructions how to implement something like this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the key event handler to the scene (not the buttons). If you add it to the buttons, they will only be invoked if the button has keyboard focus.

Comment: `onKeyReleased` seems like a better option than `onKeypress` in this situations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I added the following code snippet in App.java:

```
scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(KeyEvent event) {         
    controller.numFromKeyboard(event.getCode().toString());
   }
});
```

And also, I had to add:

```
Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController(); 
              // The above line MUST be
              // inserted after root is loaded in order the controller of my 
              // app to be instantiated, 
              // otherwise we will get a null exception when handler will be 
              // invoked
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

 //controller  = new Controller();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        // Read file fxml and draw interface.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass()
                .getResource("/application/View.fxml"));


        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/application/application.css").toExternalForm());
        Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application/Assets/App.png"));
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Calculator by Dimitris Baltas");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);         
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
               controller.numFromKeyboard(event.getCode().toString());
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```